Need MariaDB 10.5 for Ubuntu 22.04
It seems like MariaDB 10.5 is no longer available for Ubuntu 22.04, but I need it urgently.
[error] MariaDB Server 10.5 is not available for Ubuntu Jammy

Can someone help me out with that?

What do you mean no longer available? Was it available before? Where was it available? Is it on the official repositories?

MariaDB has its own APT repositories. You could follow their installation instructions for debs and pick 10.5

If specific versions of software are required, Docker may be a good way forward. This allows for a specific version to be installed that will not be updated to newer versions as the host OS receives updates.
